# Downloadable content as in-app-purchase on iOS < 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, in-app-purchase

According to [iOS developer library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction/downloads) `downloads` property exists only in iOS SDK 6.0 or later.

Is there way to make in-app-purchases with downloadable content on older version of iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't seen the SKDownloads stuff before, but I did find this description of it:  http://xinsight.ca/blog/iap-content-download-in-ios6/

To answer your question, yes you can make in-app-purchases with downloadable content from your own server(s).  That capability has been available since IAP was introduced a few years ago.  What you want is the "Server Product Model" as described in the In-App-Purchase Programming guide:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1